# || and && in a single if statement

Tags: java

I'm getting some peculiar output from a program in which I have a few if statements like this:

```
if((m.getLeft(position).state == position.state.wall || m.getLeft(position).state == position.state.border) 
    && (m.getBelow(position).state == position.state.open || m.getBelow(position).state == position.state.visited)){
    check = true;
}
```

where I have both && and || used in the same if condition. I want the boolean check to be made true if the cell at getLeft() is either a wall or a border AND the cell at getBelow() is either open or visited.

Does this code, the way I have it written now, perform this check properly? Perhaps more importantly, is it poor form to write a statement like this? Would it be better to break it up into two statements?

I'm not sure whether the peculiarities I'm seeing are resulting from these statements or something else, my question is more about general best practices.

EDIT: Thanks for all the input. I suspected as much (that it was too complicated), which was why I framed my question the way I did.

***EDIT (a year later, looking back)*** (to restate the above more strenuously) for the love of god, don't write anything like the `if` statement above. If you find yourself with a similar line of code, remember [occam's razor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor) is perhaps nowhere more applicable than in programming.

Comment: Your if-statement is very complicated. I think this makes it harder to understand. I think the REAL solution you need is to break it up into two if-statements, or to refactor your method to not need such complication.

Comment: I fail to see the complexity or a real question here. If either of the first two conditions resolve to `true` AND either of the second two conditions resolve two `true` ... then you set `check` to `true`. This is a pretty basic `if` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your complicated `if` statement can be refactored as:

```
if((m.getLeft(position).state == position.state.wall || m.getLeft(position).state == position.state.border)) {
    if((m.getBelow(position).state == position.state.open || m.getBelow(position).state == position.state.visited)){
        check = true;
    }
}
```

Thanks to @Makoto:

```
check = ((m.getLeft(position).state == position.state.wall || m.getLeft(position).state == position.state.border)) && ((m.getBelow(position).state == position.state.open || m.getBelow(position).state == position.state.visited));
```

And your code, as well as this code "works".

But also, remember, stick to a naming convention that is mentioned in Java's Style Guidelines. I have no idea what `m` in your code is. This kind of naming an object reference must be avoided. Also, `state` seems to be a `public` field in your class (assuming). Such public access fields should also be avoided. Instead use `getters()` and `setters()`.

Comment: ...why not just assign `check` to the result of the boolean comparison...?

Comment: @Makoto yeah that too will do.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me that it performs properly, however it is rather difficult to read.

If you're going to be using an `&&` in an if statement, you may as well nest a new if statement instead, it is essentially the same thing in most cases.

Comment: It's not the same if there is an else statement, you would have to duplicate that code to get the same effect.

Comment: @Arjan where you'd use an else statement that'd duplicate code - you'd be better off using `||` if I'm understanding you right. But even so, this is why I said essentially in most cases, not definitely in all.

Answer (score 1):

Breaking down your boolean statement, it reads something like this:

```
(a == x_1 || a == x_2) && (b == x_3 || b == x_4)
```

Unfortunately, that's about as simple as that particular boolean statement will get.  There are options to make the pain a lot easier:

- Refactor your code to not need such complex statements, by breaking it up into two if-blocks (as shown in my refactor below), or
- Extract that as a method and assign the return value to `check`.  Honestly, it's either going to be true or false.

Here's an example of the refactor method.  I don't know what `m` is precisely:

```
public boolean isCheck(M m, Position p) {
    boolean retVal = false;

    if(m.getLeft(p).state == p.state.wall || m.getLeft(p).state == p.state.border)) {
        if((m.getBelow(p).state == p.state.open || m.getBelow(p).state == p.state.visited))
            retVal = true;
         }
     }

     return retVal;
 }

 // call it as such

 check = isCheck(m, position);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use another `IF` insted of using `&&`:

```
if(m.getLeft(position).state == position.state.wall || 
   m.getLeft(position).state == position.state.border){
   if(m.getBelow(position).state == position.state.open || 
      m.getBelow(position).state == position.state.visited){
         check = true;
   }
}
```